# iOS UIAlertView Permissions Alpha Shadow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uialertview

Is it possible to adjust the opacity of the shadow that animates over the view when iOS triggers an UIAlertView when asking user device permissions during registration? (i.e. Location, Contact, Bluetooth, etc.)

I've searched every where, but can only find references to subclasses that *mimic* desired affect elsewhere in an app, but not actually override default behavior.

I don't have reputation over 10 to post image :(

Comment: That seems impossible

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is not possible. Well you CAN subclass an UIAlertView, edit some views etc. but this will most likely lead to rejection by Apple. Sadly, as you mentioned, the only way around this is usually making your own control that mimics the behavior of UIAlertView.

Comment: This would most definitely get rejected by Apple as `UIAlertView` is to be used as is and should NOT be subclassed.